# Long exposure and IR with Hasselblad 500cm

Tags: long-exposure, medium-format, infrared, hasselblad

I have two basic questions about the Hasselblad 500cm since I could not find an answer elsewhere.

1. Which remote cable release (possibly brand/model number) can hold the shutter down, for very long exposure?
2. Which filter can I use for infrared photography (with a Zeiss planar 80mm 2.8)?
3. Is metering going to be the same as in 35mm? Meaning, with a metering app for full frame, I can use the same settings with medium format?

Comment: When you say IR...are you wanting to know about capturing *just* the IR spectrum? Which film will you be using?

Comment: what have you googled on your own for 1) and 2) ? For 3) exposure setting are only taking into account F number and ISO

Comment: @Corey I was thinking about Rollei Infrared 135/36

Comment: Bob - what part of the light spectrum are you wanting to photograph? Rollei's IR is sensitive up to 820nm. But, are you looking to expose *only* IR light (700 - 820nm) or maybe *some* red (600 - 820nm)? This impacts the filter you'll use, how you compose, and how you meter. So...what's your goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Hasselblad, but I shoot medium format IR with Bronica (different in detail, the same in principle).

1) you don't need *extremely* long exposure times with IR photography. The typical exposure times are in the area of "just not quite handholdable" - my typical exposure is 1/15 of a second at *f* 16.
So you definitely want to use a tripod, and perhaps lock your mirror if your camera allows, but do not need a special remote release of the lockable kind.

2) there are just two IR sensitive films manufactured as of now: [Rollei Infrared](https://www.foto-r3.com/files/Rollei_Infrared400_ING.pdf) and [Ilford SFX200](https://www.ilfordphoto.com/amfile/file/download/file_id/1904/product_id/702/).
Neither of them reaches very far into IR when compared to a converted digital camera, so you have to be careful with your choice of filter - if you go too far you risk an empty film. The gold standard of IR film photography seems to be [Hoya R72](http://www.hoyafilter.com/hoya/products/specialeffectsfilters/r72infrared/), which is what I use.

3) the emulsions of IR sensitive 120 film are the same as for 135 film, so metering is in theory the same. But - and it is a big but :) - there is no exposure meter available for IR light only. So you have to measure the visible light, and bracket. For a sunny day and R72 filter the difference is usually about 5-6 stops.

Here is one of my photos on flickr - follow [the link](https://flic.kr/p/HXy4o4) for exposure information. I used a tripod and R72 filter, but not a special cable release  (just my regular one, and the MLU lever)

[image: https://flic.kr/p/HXy4o4]